# Rails errors using whenever

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, whenever

Hi I've migrated from Rails 3.2.12 to finally 4.2.0

now I got this erros while using whenever for scheduling cronjobs

```
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler.rb:122:in `setup'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/setup.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
  from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
  from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize': Could not find minitest-5.2.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:132:in `specs'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:177:in `specs_for'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:166:in `requested_specs'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler.rb:122:in `setup'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/setup.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
  from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
  from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize': Could not find minitest-5.2.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

How can I fix this?

my Gemfile looks like this:

```
 source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
gem "airbrake"
#gem "mysql"
#gem 'mysql2',  '~>0.3.7'
gem 'mysql2', '~>0.3.9'
gem 'fastercsv'
gem 'newrelic_rpm', :group => [:production, :staging]
gem "xml-simple", :require => "xmlsimple"
gem "will_paginate", "~> 3.0.0"
gem "json", '1.7.7'
gem "default_value_for"
gem "whenever"
gem 'charlock_holmes'
gem 'prototype-rails', github: 'rails/prototype-rails', branch: '4.2'
gem 'rails_autolink'
gem 'mocha'
gem 'daemons'
gem "paperclip", "~> 4.2"

group :development do
  gem 'capistrano'
  gem 'capistrano-ext'
  gem 'railroady'
  gem 'minitest', '5.2'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end
```

Comment: What does your gemfile look like? You may have to specify a different version of `minitest` than `minitest-5.2.0`. This is the error: *Could not find minitest-5.2.0 in any of the sources*

Comment: added gemfile above ... also tried without minitest version

Comment: wen I only take gem 'minitest' I got this error all the time: `Could not find minitest-5.6.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.`

Comment: try removing your gemfile.lock and `bundle` again

Comment: tried and tried and tried ... I've deleted it and tried again ... `when i run this: `sudo rake crons:generate` I got this error: 
git://github.com/rails/prototype-rails.git (at 4.2) is not yet checked out. Run `bundle install` first ... bundle install dosn't change anything

Comment: try running `sudo bundle` and then run your `sudo cron` command.